# How to make alternative for itemselector in modern version ExtJs

Tags: extjs, extjs6-modern

In classic version sencha I use `itemselector`, but in modern it dose not work:

```
{
        xtype: 'itemselector',
        name: 'itemselector',
        id: 'pointsSelector',            
        height: '80%',
        displayField: 'text',
        valueField: 'id',
        margin: 10,            
        listConfig: {
            getInnerTpl: function () {
                return '<i class="x-fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {text}';
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (el) {
                console.log(el.getConfig());
            }
        }
    }
```

What is alternative for that element in modern sencha app?